Kafka consumer reads same message again after consumer group rebalances
I am using a Node JS based application using node-rdkafka library. I have two consumers running in my application both running on same consumer group id G1.
consumer1 is reading from topic1 and consumer2 is reading from topic2.
autoCommit is disabled. I am manually committing each offset after message processing.
Both topics have only one partition.
MAX_MESSAGE_POLL is set to 1. So I am polling only 1 message at a time from broker.
What I am noticing is, that if consumer1 is in middle of message processing and in the meantime consumer2 comes up. Consumer1 will re-read the same message again. I enabled rebalance_cb in kafka consumer config and got to know that broker rebalances consumer group whenever a new consumer joins the group. It revokes and re-assigns the same partition again (since there is only one partition)
Question 1: Why is consumer1 reading the same message again even after successfully committing the current offset?
Another thing i noticed is that if i provide a default implementation of rebalance_cb from https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-rdkafka#rebalancing
That is the below code:
'rebalance_cb': (err, assignment) => {

      if (err.code === Kafka.CODES.ERRORS.ERR__ASSIGN_PARTITIONS) {
        // Note: this can throw when you are disconnected. Take care and wrap it in
        // a try catch if that matters to you
        this.consumer.assign(assignment);
      } else if (err.code == Kafka.CODES.ERRORS.ERR__REVOKE_PARTITIONS){
        // Same as above
        this.consumer.unassign();
      } else {
        // We had a real error
        console.error(err);
      }
  
    }`

In this case, message is NOT read twice.
Question 2: What is causing consumer1 to NOT read the same message again when providing a default implementation of rebalance_cb ? I mean without this function also, node-rdkafka must be following same strategy.
My expectation is that after a successful commit, same message should never be read again from same consumer group.
